# Graph , why Sum of graph vertex degree is always even?

Tags: c++, graph, vertex, degrees

Please answer me that question

> A degree of a vertex is the number of other vertices connected to it. Show that the the sum of the graph vertex degrees is always even.

it is related to graphs in C++

Comment: I think it was asked that **you** should show that, not us?!?

Comment: i don't know so i am asking , if u don't know why , it's OK , 

thanks for -ve vote πάντα ῥεῖ -_-

Comment: Check [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the help center 1st before posting questions here please. It will explain what and how can be asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First link in a Google search brings us to ...  [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181833/proving-that-the-number-of-vertices-of-odd-degree-in-any-graph-g-is-even)

> The sum of all the degrees is equal to twice the number of edges.
>   Since the sum of the degrees is even and the sum of the degrees of
>   vertices with even degree is even, the sum of the degrees of vertices
>   with odd degree must be even. If the sum of the degrees of vertices
>   with odd degree is even, there must be an even number of those
>   vertices.

By the way this has nothing to do with "C++ graphs". It is a general property of graphs as per their mathematical definition

Edit :

This statement is  only valid for **undirected graphs**, and is called the [Handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

Comment: Thanks , i saw that before but i didn't know that graphs we have studied in C++ is already a math object , i thought that something else , Thanks Karim

Comment: @ViRus-B0y _'... in C++ is already a math object ...'_ Uhmm, what please? Did you panic accept? What's a _c++ math object_ after all, could you elaborate on your enlightenment/understanding now?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ do u have a problem with me ?!!

Comment: @ViRus-B0y _'do u have a problem with me'_ Certainly not, I just can't understand what you're talking about. Are you learning _C++ by buzzwords_??

Comment: For clarity, you should include that this only holds for undirected graphs, as it says in the link. Also, I'm fairly sure you confused @ViRus-B0y by using the term "mathematical object" since C++ is object-oriented. It would have been better worded as something like "as per the mathematical definition".×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: Sure. Edited for clarity, for future readers.